# Problema con fetch debido a CORS policy

Tags: javascript, fetch, cors

Estoy tratando de enviar el contenido de un formulario vía fetch hacia la api de un CRM con una URL dada, pero no logro configurar bien el CORS para que el servidor de destino me acepte los datos. Intenté configurando el "mode" y después añadiéndole headers relacionados a CORS, pero aún así no funciona.
[image: Errores en consola de Chrome]

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:** Le cambié el "mode" a "no-cors" y el servidor al parecer ya me acepta los datos, pero me envía una respuesta que no es la que se supone que me debería enviar. La adjunto a continuación:
[image: Respuesta del fetch una vez cambiado "mode" a "no-cors"]

```
window.addEventListener('load',function(){
 var formContacto = document.querySelector("#formContact");
 var btnFormulario = document.querySelector("#btnFormulario");
 btnFormulario.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var nombreApellido = document.querySelector("#nombreApellido");
    var email = document.querySelector("#email");
    var telefono = document.querySelector("#telefono");
    var rut = document.querySelector("#rut");
    var programa = document.querySelector("#programa");
    var modalidad = document.querySelector("#modalidad");
    var mensaje = document.querySelector("#mensaje");
    const objectForm = {
        nombre: nombreApellido.value,
        email: email.value,
        telefono: telefono.value,
        rut: rut.value,
        programa: programa.value,
        modalidad: modalidad.value,
        mensaje: mensaje.value
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(objectForm));
    fetch('https://advance.uniacc.crm-mantis.cl/webservice/formulario_web.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
            /*"Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Content-Type",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": 'https://advance.uniacc.crm-mantis.cl/webservice/formulario_web.php'*/
        },
        data: JSON.stringify(objectForm)
    }).then(resp => console.log(resp.json))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
})
})
```

Comment: CORS no se soluciona desde el cliente... se soluciona desde el servidor. Tienes acceso al código del CRM?

Comment: @Pipe no, no tengo acceso, pero hago pruebas desde Postman y me resultan. No entiendo por qué desde acá no

Comment: El problema es que el navegador fuerza que las reglas de CORS se cumplan, mientras que postman no actúa como un navegador, solo hace peticiones HTTP. Por eso desde el navegador no funciona y desde postman si. Cuando usas postman, se ignoran las reglas de CORS

Comment: @Pipe qué me recomiendas hacer en ese caso para configurar bien el fetch?

Comment: No puedes hacer nada... como te dije en el primer comentario, eso lo solucionas desde el servidor, si no tienes acceso a el debes solicitar a los administradores que te agreguen tu dominio a los dominios permitidos por CORS... desde el cliente no puedes hacer nada.

Comment: La unica un poco engorrosa, sería que hicieras tu propio servidor, para que fuera ese servidor el que hiciera la peticion y luego le devolviera los datos a tu página... pero directamente desde tu página no puedes hacer nada

Comment: @Pipe agradecido por la ayuda